# insert missing period at end of paragraph in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

i receive reports (word document in   .doc format ) from clients which due to some processes at their end are missing periods () at the end of most paragraphs. I have to manually add periods. Is there any code in word vba macros to accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there is code to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Set doc = ActiveDocument 
Set rngRange = _ 
 doc.Range(doc.Paragraphs(1).Start, _ 
 doc.Paragraphs(1).End - 1) 
rngRange.InsertAfter _ 
******


Dim MyText As String
   Dim MyRange As Object
   Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Range
   MyText = "."
   MyRange.InsertAfter (MyText)

Comment: This is what I could come up with, in bits and pieces. But how to make it a functional code, I am unable to. Needless to say I am a newbie. would appreciate help. Thank you.

Comment: any suggestions from dear members please. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly simple example on how to add a period to every paragraph that contains text. You could extend it to see if the paragraph really has no period at the end but I leave that up to you to decide.

Call the Macro from the Developer Tab after you added the macro:

```
Sub TestAddPeriod()

  Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim text As String

  For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
      If Len(oPara.Range.text) > 1 Then
         Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(oPara.Range.Start, oPara.Range.End - 1)
         rng.InsertAfter "."
      End If
   Next

End Sub
```